# Why use '@' in JavaScript comments - @param

Tags: javascript, node.js

Reading JavaScript code on git I have noticed often there is the @ symbol before a word in the comments IE @param, @chainable, @return
I read the stackoverflow questions and replies about JavaScript comments in one reply there was mention of 'supported' words for comments. I have no idea what is happening, or why and google seems empty.

What is meant by 'supported' words for comments?
Why use the @ symbol before the 'supported' words?

Comment: `->` http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html

Comment: It's just a notation used in JSDoc. It's presumably inspired by the same sort of thing done in Java.

Comment: `->` https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/about-getting-started in case usejsdoc.org is down

Answer (score 0):

A couple different reasons...

- It makes it easier to read those as "headers" in your comment
- It's easy to make a parser without mistaking them as just use of the word "param" in your comment.
- It's a standard outlined by JSDoc
- It's a practice adopted by a lot of other languages.

It's just the standard that you'll see in comments.